# How to run a makefile on Windows?

Tags: python, windows, makefile

This is the content of the makefile:

```
.PHONY: all
all:
    python3 main.py

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm *.pyc figures/*png
```

There are many files of python? How to run this project on windows?

Answer (score 0):

To create a script for making files on multiple platforms, you can perform it with some methods:

first, you can get the os type and perform makefile according to it, like this :

```
if sys.platform.startswith('win'):
    #do somethings
else:
    #do something else :)
```

second, you can use python builtin library to handle it(i preferred it):

```
f= open("testfile.txt","w+")
for i in range(10):
         f.write("This is line %d\r\n" % (i+1))
    f.close()
```